# Составление пути для Frontend разработчика

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

Я будущий Фронтенд разработчик..

Мои знания технологий в верстке: HTML,CSS,SCSS, ну и как же без Bootstrap 
Сейчас у меня проблема с JavaScript точнее непонимание работы с DOM ( я уже много видео пересмотрел по поводу работы с DOM'ом но все говорили о самых простых делах с ним) я подумал может мне перейти на jQuery.. но можно ли начать учить библиотеку jQuery если у меня почти нулевые знания в ДОМ?!

Ну и главный вопрос - могу ли я спокойно переходить на фреймворк Реакт после ДОМа?

Спасибо за ваш ответ!

Comment: Я бы советовал вообще jQuery не трогать. Работать с DOM прекрасно можно и без него. React не простой framework который потребует от вас хотя бы базового понимания JavaScript. Если вам пока сложно разобраться с DOM, лучше попрактикуйтесь в нем побольше прежде чем браться за React. Попробуйте например создать калькулятор, в котором кнопки генерируются из JS. Сделайте кнопку плюс так, чтобы она занимала размер двух кнопок.

Answer (score 3):

Сейчас меня закидают тухлыми помидорами и скажут что мне надо идти читать книжки, иначе я не смогу работать =)

Но я просто расскажу как учился. Начинал я с jquery и просто делал всё по шаблонам, а когда сталкивался с чем-либо на что у меня не было шаблона, то я шёл в гугл и искал новый шаблон. Со временем я начал понимать как работает jquery и мне больше не нужно было искать шаблоны и работать по шаблонам, я уже стал понимать что я должен сделать чтобы получить это и подвинуть то.

Потом я перешёл во vue и начал работать по шаблонам там, произошло тоже самое, что и с jquery, я быстро начал понимать как и что тут устроенно и уже мог сам писать код без гугла и шаблонов, понимая, что я хочу и как это получить.

Потом я уже стал понимать нативный JS и узнал что такое `document.querySelector` и т.п. Да да! Только после jquery и vue.

Такой подход к изучению позволил мне меньше чем за год стать неплохим разработчиком и я уже могу делать практически всё, хоть писать новый google или stackoverflow =). Я так учил Python, Django, Node.js и многое другое. Если вас отправляют читать документацию то плохой совет. Читать её имеет смысл, когда вы уже понимаете "язык программистов". А новички, как правило, не понимают её, но бородатые дядьки будут вас пинать туда всё время, не слушайте их, на ютубе полно уроков для начинающих, где вы можете просто повторять за автором и это даст вам опыт, понимание и новые шаблоны =).

Я считаю, что сначала всё-таки нужно поездить на машине, а потом уже смотреть под капот. И так во всём мире. Это самый лучший подход к изучению (уже вижу рейтинг -10 и тухлые помидоры, летящие в меня =)). Либо вы можете потратить 5 лет на чтение книжек и изучения азов, но потом вы всё равно будете искать ответ на stackoverflow, а ответит вам "Вася", который понятия не имеет что там за книжки и что за там эльфийский язык вообще, но он будет понимать что нужно сделать, а вы нет.

P.S. Моё мнение. Можете закидывать меня чем хотите, но я его не изменю. Учился так, учусь и буду. Если вы скажите, что это плохой подход, то это будет вашим мнением. Неужели вы считаете своё мнение более правильным чем мнение других людей? Почему? Только потому что вы так решили?)

Comment: когда впервые увидел ванильку js пару лет назад - вызвало какое-то дикое отторжение (страшно представить, что было еще до этого)... Соответственно так же начал обмазываться jquery. Ну а когда понимание более или менее пришло + ванилька сильно апнулась - балуюсь без "обмазывания" )

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю тебе нужно сначало понять DOM перед тем как начинать учить jquery. Так как в jquery много работы с DOM. На счет реакта, лучше выучить основы прежде чем переходить к framework'ам.